# How do i avoid the function stack memory usage in BackTrack algorithm (n-queens)

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, n-queens

I started some coding on C# and tried n-queen's problem with slight change(queen also has knight power).After a limit it starts showing the stackoverflow issue due to calling the function again and again.

Could anyone please help me in understanding problem i am facing.Below is the code for n-queens problem.

```
private int[] BackTrack(int queenRow, int column)
{
    for (int i = column; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (CheckValidMove(queenRow, i))
        {
            queenPosition[queenRow++] = i;
            if (queenRow < size)
                return BackTrack(queenRow, 0);
            else
            {
                done = true;
                return queenPosition;   
            }
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    if ((queenRow - 1) >= 0 && ((queenPosition[queenRow - 1] + 1) <= size))
    {
        return BackTrack(queenRow - 1, queenPosition[queenRow - 1] + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return queenPosition;
    }
}
```

1. Here `queenPosition` (returned by the function) is the array which
   has the column number where the queen is placed. Like `queenPosition`
   for 4-queen would be (2->0->3->1). The position in 4x4 chessboard.
2. `CheckValid` function validates whether the position is suitable or not.
3. There is some concept which I am not aware of and the memory is getting wasted.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```
    if ((queenRow - 1) >= 0 && ((queenPosition[queenRow - 1] + 1) <= size))
    {
       return BackTrack(queenRow - 1, queenPosition[queenRow - 1] + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return queenPosition;
    }
```

To

```
    if (!((queenRow - 1) >= 0 && ((queenPosition[queenRow - 1] + 1) <= size)))
    {
       return queenPosition;
    }

    return BackTrack(queenRow - 1, queenPosition[queenRow - 1] + 1);
```

You need to help the compiler and [optimize](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4.aspx) it to [tail](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/09/02/tail-recursion-in-c/) [recursion](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43234/C-A-Method-for-Tail-Call-Recursion).

It might not get optimized at all, this depending on the parameters and the return values, but it's worth a try.

A good reading regarding this problem [N-Queens Problem Solutions by Lauschke Consulting](http://www.lauschkeconsulting.com/nqueens.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Oops! didn't see the recursive call at the beginning: return BackTrack(queenRow, 0); Anyway, you get the idea. Move the recursive call to the end of the function and make sure it is only one.

Comment: C# compiler does not optimize to make use of tail call recursion. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/166013/c-compiler-should-optimize-tail-calls

Comment: Changed the answer. I was under the assumption they did it in 4.0.